# Mysql: Setting date = todays date

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to set DateOfLastupdate as today's date.I have tried this

```
update Products set DateOfLastupdate = (SELECT date(now());
```

but this is not working.but

```
SELECT date(now());
```

this can give currentdate.Does anyone has solution for this?How can i set current date as DateOflastupdate?

Comment: "but this is not working" why you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This...
Curdate return only current date. FOr more use this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

```
update Products set DateOfLastupdate = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
update Products set DateOfLastupdate = CURDATE();  /* Date part only */
```

or if you want the date and time

```
update Products set DateOfLastupdate = NOW();  /* Date and time */
```

Comment: THANKS IT WORKS.  PREVIOUSLY IT WAS NOT WORKING USING CURDATE BECAUSE TYPE OF DateOfLastupdate was not date...

Comment: but if want to set this as soon as that respective row is updated,what should i do? It must be automatically update that field with curdate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `current_date()` if you only need the date part, otherwise use `current_timestamp()` or `now()`.

```
update Products set DateOfLastupdate = current_date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do a select, it's much easier if you use:

```
UPDATE products set DateOfLastUpdate = now();
```

Be aware that the now() function  is an entire date, including the hour, minutes and seconds. 
If you want to just put the date, consider making a substring as well.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/string-functions.html

Answer (score -1):

If you used this in Sql server so, please use this,

```
Update Product set DateOfLastUpdate = GetDate()
```

And use My Sql then

```
Update Product set DateOfLastUpdate = CURDATE();
```

Comment: OP has tagged this for mysql

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
udpate Products set DateOfLastupdate= current_date();
```

or

```
udpate table tblName set mytime =concat(current_date(),TIME(mytime))
```